# Soundcloud API not fetching all tracks by a user

Tags: soundcloud

Iam using the Sound cloud API to fetch tracks by users. But for some reason the tracks that i get back from the API is missing a lot of tracks from the users actual account. The user has about 1000 tracks but my json is only getting a fraction of those.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the limit of entries in the JSON response is, but I think it's 200. That means, if a user has more than 200 tracks uploaded, and you want to get the tracks, the JSON response only includes 200 tracks, **BUT** there is a "next_href" cursor. Use that cursor to fetch the next 200 tracks and so on.

For example: if I fetch my latest activities, I only fetch about 30 at a time (*setting limit=30*). If I want to get more than 30, I just use the next_href cursor.

```
"next_href": "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/activities.json?limit=30&cursor=asdf1234
```

(I replaced my cursor with "asdf1234".)

So, just use that cursor for fetching. Hope I could help!